# Ternary operator usage

Tags: c#, .net, ternary-operator

Whats wrong with this seemingly straightforward code?

```
invoice.GST > gstValue ? invoice.GST -= gstValue : invoice.GST = 0;
```

VS complains
*Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*

Comment: ternary operator is just that, an operator, not a statement (like if).

Comment: Yes. I knew its an operator, I wrote it in the question but I still treated it as a statement! God save me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
invoice.GST = ((invoice.GST>gstValue)?(invoice.GST - gstValue):0);
```

Comment: This worked  `invoice.GST = (invoice.GST > gstValue) ? (invoice.GST -= gstValue) : 0;` Thanks Cybernate!

Comment: @Reddy: It works because the `-=` operator returns the value being assigned.  You could change `-=` to `-` and it'd have the same effect (and look less weird to boot).

Answer (score 3):

Because you cannot use `invoice.GST > gstValue ? invoice.GST -= gstValue : invoice.GST = 0;` as a statement (like VS told you). Same like you cannot do this: `int i = 0; i;`

You could write it as: `invoice.GST = Math.Max(0, invoice.GST - gstValue);`

Answer (score 1):

```
invoice.GST = invoice.GST > gstValue ? invoice.GST - gstValue : 0;
```

The ternary **operator** is like *-*, *+*, *%* and other operators.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions mentioned make sense to use as statements, because they cause side effects.

Generally it doesn't make sense to have an operation with no side effects as a statement, because removing the operator and just evaluating the operands would have the same effect, these usually indicate that the behavior is not what the programmer intended.

The exceptions to this are the three operators which conditionally evaluate their operands (the other two are `&&` and `||`) -- eliminate the operator and the side effect of the operand changes.  In C and C++ you will sometimes find these operators used solely to cause conditional evaluation, but C# does not allow this.  In all three cases, the conditional evaluation can be gotten using an `if` statement, which also makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
invoice.GST -= invoice.GST > gstValue ? gstValue : invoice.GST;
```